# RoR - Don't destroy object, just flag as hidden

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple model in RoR and I would like to keep eveything people enter on the site. But I also want to be able to hide some content if the user click on "Remove".

So I added a bolean attribute in my model called "displayed".

I would like to know, what would be the best-practices-styled method.

I guess I have to change the controller with something like :

```
def destroy
 @point = Point.find(params[:id])
 @point.displayed = false
 @point.save

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to points_url }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
```

But I am not sure it is clean. What would be the best way to do it.

As you guess I am noobish with RoR. Chunks of code would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this:

```
class Point < ActiveRecord::Base

  def archive        
    update_attribute!(:displayed, false)
  end 

end
```

And then call `@point.archive` in the destroy action of your controller where you would normally call `@point.destroy`. You can also create a `default_scope` to hide archived points until you explicitly query for them, seethe RoR guide on [appling a default scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#applying-a-default-scope).

**Edit: Updated my answer as per normalocity & logan's comments below.**

Comment: This changes the assumed meaning of `destroy`, which isn't going to be obvious to someone casually reading the controller code. The `displayed` attribute can be updated via the already present `update` action in the controller, like any other field would be. Also, the `archivable` method essentially operates as a constant since it requires a code change to alter this attribute. Because of this I'm not sure, if you even wanted to turn this on/off, why a method would be better than a constant in this case.

Comment: @normalocity Great points, I adjusted my answer to assume that the model is always meant to be soft deleted for consistency. I agree that this approach is a little unassuming, I'm not sure what the best way to get around that would be, save for leaving a comment in the code. As for what was said about the update method - it sounds like OP doesn't want users to have control of this attribute, i.e., it wouldn't be a field they can toggle on and off in an update form.

Comment: I agree that your updated answer is more clear in terms of the intention, but it still changes the meaning of calling `destroy`, which I think is the main thing I take issue with. I'm not saying that your approach won't work, just that changing the meaning of that method has some tradeoffs that, on their own, may not be obvious.

Comment: To your point about the OP not wanting users to have control of this attribute, I guess I don't see the difference between providing a control in the UI for a user to affect the value of that attribute (which seems to be what's wanted in, "I also want to be able to hide some content if the user click on "Remove"), and allowing its direct change via the `update` action. The result is the same. If archiving needs to be restricted to only some users then that would be the job of the authorization components of the app to prevent, and isn't directly related to the updating of the attribute itself.

Comment: Touché, but how exactly would the direct change in the update action work out? Assuming that there are instances where the update action is called and the record is not being archived but simply updated? Obviously you would need some sort of logic to determine if the object is to be archived a la some special parameter that gets passed in. But that introduces an extra check that needs to be made on normal update operations every time.

Comment: I don't understand. There's no special attribute. You just pass it like any other attribute. If the record we were updating were an instance of a model called `Invoice` the params would look something like: `params[:invoice][:archived]` and its value would be either true or false. This is the kind of thing I'm talking about - the gems make this seem like a hard problem - it's not. There's an attribute on the model called `archived` and it's updated the same way **any other attribute** is updated, by passing it as part of the `params` hash to the controller.

Comment: I assumed it would have been a blacklisted attribute if we weren't allowing users to control it. What your saying does make sense though, it probably is better suited for an update method without making things too complex. I'd mark your answer as the accepted one if I could.

Comment: This does NOT work, as soon at false is returned the activemodel rollsback the transaction, including whatever saves or updates done in the archive function.

Comment: downvoted answer - I found it just as easy to add a checkbox that set an 'archived' attribute as I did to use 'destroy' which, as discussed above, overrides the meaning of what destroy does.

Comment: @rich I'm glad you found something that worked for you. OP wanted this functionality for his entire website though, not just one model. This seemed like the lowest hanging fruit to me as it only requires a slight modification to the model with 0 changes required in the schema, views, or controllers.

Comment: @LoganBissonnette Ah, I see what you were saying now. It's strange, I've had similar code in production for a while now, is that a new feature in a more recent version of Rails?

Answer (score 13):

Implement it yourself (rather than using a gem). It's much, much easier than it seems at first, and it's less complex than any of the gems out there that **change** the meaning of the `destroy` method, which is a bad idea, in my opinion.

I'm not saying that using the gems themselves are complex - I'm saying that by changing the meaning of the `destroy` method you're changing the meaning of something that people in the Rails world take for granted - that when you call `destroy` that record is going to go away and that `destroy` maybe also be called on dependent objects if they are chained together via `dependent: destroy` callbacks.

Changing the meaning of `destroy` is also bad because in the "convention over configuration" world, when you screw with conventions you're essentially breaking the "automagic-ness" of your Rails code. All that stuff you take for granted because you read a piece of Rails code and you know that certain assumptions generally apply - those go out the window. When you change those assumptions in ways that aren't obvious you're almost certain to introduce a bug down the line because of it.

Don't get me wrong, there's nothing better than actually reading the code for checking your assumptions, but it's also nice, as a community, to be able to talk about certain things and generally have their behavior act in a certain way.

Consider the following:

- There's nothing in Rails that says you have to implement the `destroy` action in the controller, so don't. It's one of the standard actions, but it's not required.
- Use the `update` action to set and clear an `archived` boolean attribute (or something similarly named)
- I've used the `acts_as_paranoid` gem, and if you need to add any scopes to your models (other than the ones the gem provides) you're going to find yourself having to hack your way around it, turning off the default "hide archived records" scope, and when you run into that it almost immediately loses its value. Besides, that gem does almost nothing on its own, and its functionality could easily be written yourself (and I mean barely more work than installing the gem itself), so there's really no benefit to using it from that perspective.
- As previously stated, overriding the `destroy` method or action is a bad idea because it breaks the Rails (and ActiveRecord) convention as to what it means to call `destroy` on an object. Any gem that does this (`acts_as_paranoid` for example) is also breaking that convention, and you're going to wind up confusing yourself or someone else because `destroy` simply won't mean what it's supposed to mean. This adds confusion, not clarity to your code. Don't do this - you'll pay for it later.
- If you want to use a soft-delete gem because you are protecting against some theoretical, future developer who might hork up your data...well, the best solution to that is not to hire or work with those people. People that inexperienced need mentorship, not a gem to prevent them from making mistakes.
- If you really, absolutely, must prevent destroying a record of a given model (in addition to being able to simply archive it), then use the `before_destroy` callback and simply return false, which will prevent it from being destroyed at all unless an explicit call to `delete` is used (which isn't the same as destroy anyway). Also, having the callback in place makes it (a) really obvious why `destroy` doesn't work without changing its meaning, and (b) it's easy to write a test to make sure it's not destroyable. This means in the future, if you should accidentally remove that callback or do something else that makes that model destroyable, then a test will fail, alerting you to the situation.

Comment: Excellent summary, given the business rule of soft deletes only would it perhaps be better practice to remove the `destroy` methods entirely and add custom controller actions which are more aptly named?

Comment: In this case I don't think custom controller actions are necessary. Archiving a record is just setting a flag from `false` to `true` - which is what an `update` is for. If there is a specific need to treat archives/unarchives as special then I think that need should be articulated. For example, except for the fact that we're calling it "archiving", what actually makes the act of archiving something fundamentally different than updating its state? I'd venture to say that nothing makes it special, except that as developers, in our minds, it somehow seems special. I really don't think it is.

Comment: Also, "soft delete" is just a synonym for "archiving". Since there is no actual deletion happening (but a change in the state of the object - which, again, is an `update`), then calling it a "soft delete" is very misleading. I mean, I get it, I know what people mean by a "soft delete", but I'm saying just call it what it is - it's an archiving action, so call it "archive" or "hiding" or whatever makes sense in your app. I realize I'm probably going a little to far on this "soft delete" thing, but really - we don't need to use this kind of wording.

Comment: Honestly I only just recently came to learn the phrase "soft delete" from Shane Andrade's answer, "archiving" does sound a little more to the point.

Comment: Sure, and I should concede that I'm probably going overboard there. Nothing personal.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [acts_as_archive](https://github.com/winton/acts_as_archive) gem. It will do soft deletes seamlessly.

Comment: The problem with the soft delete gems is that they change the meaning of `destroy`, which isn't going to be obvious from the point of view of the controller where you'll be calling that method. The `update` action can do it better, and adding a gem for this is basically totally overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is good, but you can use the [acts_as_paranoid gem](https://github.com/goncalossilva/rails3_acts_as_paranoid) to manage that.

Comment: Same issue as the `acts_as_archive` gem.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, instead of adding a new boolean flag its better to added a `deleted_at:datetime` column

```
@point = Point.find(params[:id])
@point.touch(:deleted_at)
...
```

Then later

```
Point.where(deleted_at: nil) # these are NOT hidden
Point.where.not(deleted_at: nil) # these are hidden
```